# Django 1.6 Is there any better design for a vote model for multi-models?

Tags: django

Query desire:

1.Sort the 4 models(maybe more in the future) by its property `score`. It is said that this is very slow:

```
#`Item` represent Question, Answer, Topic or Reply.
sorted(Item.objects.all(),key=lambda i:i.score)
```

2.List the vote history for a user or an item. Obviously this is naturally solved by the model `Vote`. But if there is no such a model in the design, this desire should be realized in some other way.

My current solution is add an integer field `rate` to the four models so every time a vote action happens to it, apart from a record added in model `Vote`, its `rate` field can be saved with the value from its property `score`. But is there is any better design? Thanks.

This is the related models:

```
#models.py

class BaseAction(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")

class Vote(BaseAction):    
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0) #all possible value is -1,0 and 1

class BaseItem(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    vote = generic.GenericRelation(Vote)

    @property    
    def score(self):
        '''
        this is the key method to sort a model.
        '''
        return  sum([a.value for a in self.vote.all()])

#---there are 4 models that can be voted, maybe more in the future.------

class Question(BaseItem):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Answer(BaseItem):
    question =  models.ForeignKey(Question)

class Topic(BaseItem):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Reply(BaseItem):
    topic =  models.ForeignKey(Topic)
```

Comment: You don't need two abstract base models and I really believe you need to rethink your database design.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid There are 4 other models that subclass `BaseAction` in my project. I think this is DRY just like `BaseItem`. Could you explain why?